# How to plot the input to a state-space closed loop model?

Tags: control-systems

I have a mathematica notebook to build the state-space model of a system from its differential equations, calculate LQR gains and simulate the system response.

```
ss = StateSpaceModel[
  {eq1, eq2}, 
  {{xc'[t], 0}, {xc[t], 0}, {\[Theta]'[t], 0}, {\[Theta][t], 0}}, 
  {{F[t], 0}}, 
  {xc[t], \[Theta][t]}, 
  t
]

ssValues = With[{g = 9.8, mc = 0.5, mp = 2, mf = 0.5, lp = 0.3}, Evaluate[ss]]
```

So far, the system is unstable. Adding LQR:

```
ssValuesTracked = <|"InputModel" -> ssValues, "TrackedOutputs" -> {1, 2}|>
Q = ...
R = ...
ssValuesTrackedCL = LQRegulatorGains[ssValues, {Q, R}, "Data"]
```

Which makes the system stable when tracking an input.

```
r = {1, 0}
Plot[
    Evaluate[
        OutputResponse[{ssValuesTrackedCL, {0, 0.5, 0, 0.2}}, r, {t, 0, 10}]
    ], 
    {t, 0, 10},
    Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300, GridLines -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Automatic
]
```

Which show the response of xc and theta.

The questions is, how do I plot the values of the input u of the closed loop system in the figure below?

[image]

Comment: Most of the application examples show how this is done. e.g. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LQRegulatorGains.html#524812316

Comment: Can you provide a link to explain what does cd["ControllerModel"]? I already tried the examples provided. However, since I don't know what does cd["ControllerModel"] represents, I cannot generalize the examples to other use-cases

Comment: Please read the documentation more carefully. In the 'Details and Options' section there are block diagrams showing what ControllerModel is.